# Using subprocess module to enter key strokes into cmd

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running an executable using Popen, once the executable is running and the cmd is open I would then like to pipe two key strokes (numbers) sequentially. As the cmd prompts the user as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

How do I pipe these keystrokes (numbers) to my process using the subprocess module? My code is below, do I need to use process.communicate()?

```
# Run executable and pass an argument to that executable.

process = subprocess.Popen('CalcSoilSurfTemp.exe C:\Users\szilasia\Desktop\epws\USA_TX_Lubbock.Intl.AP.722670_TMY3.epw',stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

process.communicate() # How do I pipe keystrokes(numbers) into the process?
```

Many thanks!,

EDIT:

I used to the code - 
`process.communicate(input = '1\n2')` to enter 1 and 2 sequentially, there was no need to convert to bytes as I am using Python 2.7 and this conversion is implict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [communicate doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) says to use `input=b'<chars>'`.  The input must be bytes because input goes through a pipe, which carries binary data.  Precisely what you send depends on what the program requires.  To select the first alternative, a python program using `input()` would require `b'1\n'` whereas a program using a different input function might require just `b'1'`.  To send two choices, concatenate the two required bytes objects into one.  Be prepared to experiment.  I believe that process.communicate() can be called only once, so you must send one predetermined input stream and get two output streams after the subprocess ends.

Please let me know if this answer works on your system (Windows, it appears).

Comment: thank you it worked I simply used the code below process.communicate(input = '1\n2') I am using Python 2.7 so there is no need to convert to from string to bytes as this is automatic

Comment: In 2.7, `str is bytes`, so `b` prefix would future-proof your code.  But the need might be years away for you.